# Smarty With Zend Framework cannot find the index.tpl but clearlu displays other views

Tags: zend-framework, smarty

For the life of me, I cannot understand this particular case!
I  am working on a project on local machine and everything works fine. But after uploading it to a remote server I cam get this error

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script ''index'/index.tpl' not found in path (/home6/shawndre/application/modules/default/views/scripts/)' in /home6/shawndre/zf/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:988
```

This error only appear on the indexController indexAction page.

Im pulling my hair out on this one!
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Oh my God! The error was caused by the way i set the definition for the default controller in my application.ini
I used single quotation instead of double. Changing the value of the default controller to "index" instead of 'index' fixed it. Had me scratching my mustache! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by the way I set the definition for the default controller in my `application.ini`. I used single quotation `'` instead of double quote `"`.

Changing the value of the default controller to `"index"` instead of `'index'` fixed it. Had me scratching my mustache!